# Update new IOS certification with old one

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I have a project which was build through AppceletorStudio. I want to replace IOS certificate old one with new one. How should I replace?

Comment: just download the new certificate and compile with that! Appc Studio just reads the ones as with native development.

Comment: @RenePot how should I compile certificate? Actually I'm new on this platform.

Comment: just follow the instuctions from apple how to set up app-id's, provisioning profiles and certificates